# Is it possible to find out what program has bit defender as part of it?

Tags: windows-7, anti-virus, bitdefender

Since 2 weeks my laptop is getting quite on my nerves. On every boot I see "antivirus program cleaning the drive......not managing to delte some files and that I should contact bit defender".

There is only one single problem....I never installed bit defender on it. My normal antivirus programs said they didn't find anything when I let them run.

After looking things up a bit I saw that its possible that bit defender could be there (although not in programs & features) as part of another program.

So I'm wondering ..... is there any way to find out which program it is that is causing me this headache?

Edit:
*To make it clear I NEVER installed bit defender on that laptop (as I'm using a different anti virus program). What I DID found on the internet (google) suggested that other programs sometimes use bit defender in the background and that that COULD be related to my current situation with bit defender seemingly existing without it being installed. (although not sure if that explains that strange boot scan phenomenon I'm experiencing)*

Answer (score 1):

If Bitdefender is there you should be able to find it in the registry.

Click **Start** – **Run**, type in **regedit**, click OK to open Registry Editor, then navigate through the list to find out the below keys and delete them

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\SOFTWIN;
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\SOFTWIN;
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\XCOMM;
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\BDLM;
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\BDESRV;
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\BDUPDSVR;
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTPSRV;
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LIVESRV_EM;
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\BDSS;
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\VSSERV;
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\FILESpy;
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\REGSpy;

Also **Delete** leftover folder of Bitdefender

Open My Computer, find out and delete the following folders located in C:\

- %ProgramFiles%\SOFTWIN;
- %CommonProgramFiles%\SOFTWIN.

Comment: not the -1 voter but I'm 100% sure that I myself did not install bit defender (so also didn't remove it), but from the internet (google) it sounds like  it is possible other programs are using bit defender in the background and that my situation could be related to that.

Comment: Gotcha, well regardless if you installed it or not, if bitdefender exists in any capacity on your machine it will be in those locations.

Comment: Ah intersting. Thought those would only be there if it was directly installed. Result of the searches (looked there already before my last comment): nothing of those. So that means whatever says its bit defender is not bit defender then am I correct there?

Comment: Correct, it is most likely fake or leftover. I would check if there are any pending reboots in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SessionManager\PendingFileRenameOperations . If there are values in this key, it could give you a hint as to what's happening. Then save the key and delete it.

Comment: tnx will take a look there. (btw deinstalled my AV and also ad aware and reinstolled those since then no boot message so far).  as for the reg entry it (and pendingfilerenameoperations2) just have their own name as value

Answer (score -1):

Bitdefender has a vast number of clients for their OEM

uTorrent PRO is one of them also here is a list of oem partners

```
BullGuard
Emsisoft
eScan
F-Secure
G DATA
HAURI (ViRobot)
IMEN
Immunet
Lavasoft (Ad-Aware)
nProtect
PSafe
Quick Heal (TS)
SafeNSoft
SecurityCoverage (SecureIT)
SourceNext (ZSS only)
Tencent
ThreatTrack Vipre
TotalDefense
VirusChaser
ArcaBit
Chili Security
EstSoft (ALYac, Roboscan)
```